# Java: JList rendering effect

Tags: java, swing, jlist, cellrenderer

I have seen this effect for a list in my Netbeans. Can somebody tell me what this effect is called and how I can implement it in my custom ListCellRenderer?

Thanks for your help.

Andy

[image: JList effect]

Comment: I'm pretty sure NetBeans is written in Java/Swing and is open source. With a little bit of digging, you could probably find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you can do is use a "tooltip". This is done by:

1. invoking the `setToolTipText()` method in you renderer, or
2. overriding the `getToolTipText()` method of the JList.

Normally the tool tip appears below the mouse location. You can also override the `getToolTipLocation()` method to position the tool tip over the current row to more closely mimic the netbeans behaviour.

Comment: I have tried it with tooltips in the first place. The result was not exactly what I was looking for.